# How to make table Row Values as a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wants to make column name from Row values in Mysql Table

```
Id  Value               Type
1   ABC Bank        Bank
1   User                 Name
1   123               ID
1   user@email.com       Email
1   Banking             Reference
```

I want above to be Show like below , can you please help me to write the Query for this. Thanks in Advance

```
Id      Bank     Name         ID           Email        Reference
1     ABC Bank   User        123    User@email.com   Banking
```

Comment: You should look into making pivots in mysql. Here is a link to a sample pivot : https://riptutorial.com/mysql/example/10441/creating-a-pivot-query.

Comment: Is the number of values variable per id and is it unknown how many variables there can be and that they can be in any order?

Comment: Number of Values can be vary. it can be anything between 5 and 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when type = 'Bank' then value end) as bank,
       max(case when type = 'Name' then value end) as name,
       max(case when type = 'Id' then value end) as otherId,
       max(case when type = 'Email' then value end) as email,
       max(case when type = 'reference' then value end) as reference
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the using dynamically with PIVOT concept, but whatever [Type] field data should not actual field name, it should be different

```
CREATE TABLE PivotTable (Id INT,Value VARCHAR(100),[Type] VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO PivotTable VALUES 
 (1,'ABC Bank','Bank')      
,(1,'User','Name')          
,(1,'123','IDs')                
,(1,'user@email.com','Email')
,(1,'Banking','Reference')

SELECT * FROM PivotTable

DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Columns = STUFF((SELECT  DISTINCT ','+[Type] FROM PivotTable FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SET @SQL = 'SELECT Id,'+@Columns+' FROM 
            (
            SELECT Id,
                   Value,
                   [Type]

            FROM PivotTable
            ) P
            PIVOT
            (
            MAX(Value) FOR [Type] IN ('+@Columns+')
            )pvt'

            EXEC (@SQL)
```